# Having an issue connecting to Appium, using Eclipse

Tags: junit

When I attempt to run my code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class desiredcapab {

    @Test
    public void test() throws MalformedURLException {

        File appDir =new File("src");

        File app = new File(appDir, "Piano Tiles 1_7.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap=new DesiredCapabilities();
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, MobilePlatform.ANDROID);
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Android_Emulator");
        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, app.getAbsolutePath());
        AndroidDriver driver =new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),cap);



    }

}
```

as a JUNIT Test, I received the following Error:

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.47.1',
>   revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 02:56:46' System info: host:
>   'FUEL091', ip: '172.17.64.88', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64',
>   os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_51' Driver info:
>   driver.version: AndroidDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:589)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:155)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:109)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:39)
>     at desiredcapab.test(desiredcapab.java:30)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed
>   connection during handshake   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:134)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:143)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:134)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:568)
>     ... 30 more Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down
>   incorrectly   at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)    ...
>   50 more

Comment: Alrighty,So I figured this out, and it took me a few minute to debug this.

Changed the HTTPS:// to HTTP when providing the URL to the Driver.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty,So I figured this out, and it took me a few minute to debug this. Changed the HTTPS:// to HTTP when providing the URL to the Driver.